# Ownership of global resources after fork

Tags: c++, fork, ownership-semantics

Consider a `Foo` that holds some resource

```
struct Foo
    {
    ~Foo();
    };
```

and a global `std::vector<Foo>`. Perhaps stupid example, but it illustrates the problem well.

`std::vector<Foo> bar;`

Now, the processes `fork`s.

If `bar` is then only modified by the child process, then a call to `exit` should be the proper thing to do within the child process. If calling `_exit`, any `Foo`:s in bar would leak. If the parent added some stuff to `bar` before the fork, these object may be destroyed twice. Or maybe this is not a problem, because they should be considered as different objects.

What is the proper way of dealing with object lifetime together with a `fork`. Is the only sane way of dealing with this problems to let the child `exec` and start over?

I should notice that at this point in the program, there is guaranteed to be only one thread.

Comment: What kind of resource do `Foo`s own? Specifically, is the resource duplicated upon forking?

Comment: Forking a process effectively create a copy of the process memory. After forking, both processes own a separate copy of `bar` and modifications or destruction should not affect the other's copy. (I'm not sure if this is how every OS handles memory for forked processes though.) If `Foo` owns a resource not in the process memory (i.e. a file) then how that resource should be handled would depend on what it is.

Comment: @Romen, this could be a great answer, with just minimal extra work :-)

Comment: The title definitely transcends the scope of this question.... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way of dealing with object lifetime together with a `fork`?

The proper way to handle shared resources when forking depends on what those objects or resources are.

For any object or variable in the process memory, you [automatically get a copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) of it upon forking. Each process will then be able to modify or destroy *any* variable without affecting the other process. This also means that each process is responsible for cleaning up its unique copy of the resource.

---

For other resources that exist *outside* the process, like a file, web socket, or shared memory; The best way to handle them will depend on what that resource is. Normally those best practices will be outlined by the library / API you are using to create those resources initially.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've `fork`ed, your variables exhibit [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) semantics, so any changes by the child process result in unique variables for the child not shared with the parent. Similarly, changes in the parent process will result in the child having new copies and do not propagate, so the parent can go as far as to `exit` without interrupting the child. I've done this to implement a self-updating program.

Note that as stated in other answers, "global resources" should be treated on a case by case basis, but variables are not global resources.